# Java 7 error on multi-catch exception

Tags: playframework, java-7, multi-catch

I run my java application on a MacOS 10.9.5 (Mavericks) with JavaSE 1.7.0_60 installed.

I want to use the multi-catch statement for catch some exceptions...
But When I try to run my app I got an error like this:

```
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /tresTest/authenticate
Compilation error (In /app/controllers/TestBoxController.java around line 57)
The file /app/controllers/TestBoxController.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

The reason of this error is this line of code:

```
try {
  class.someMethodTrowingException();
} catch (MyExceptionNo1 | MyExceptionNo2 | MyExceptionNo3 e) {
  doSomethigUseful();
}
```

If type `java -version` on my console, i got this result:

```
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

I can't understand why I got this behavior. Multi-catch statement is allow in Java7, right?

---

#### UPDATE 10.15.2014

I know that if I use catch in this way everything go right

```
try {
  class.someMethodTrowingException();
} catch (MyExceptionNo1 e1) {
  doSomethigUseful();
} catch (MyExceptionNo2 e2) {
  doSomethigUseful();
} catch (MyExceptionNo3 e3) {
  doSomethigUseful();
}
```

But my goal it to use the multi-catch statement like `catch (MyExceptionNo1 | MyExceptionNo2 | MyExceptionNo3 e) {...}`

Check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

#### UPDATE 11.20.2014

Found out the problem. It's Play that use 1.6 Java compatibility even if I told to its to not use it. Don't understand yet why, and don't understand yet how to sole, but at least I understand where problem is... :)

Comment: I think it is the | part

Comment: try to put each Myexception in its own catch

Comment: Problem is in the compiler... Even if I got JDK7 it compile for JDK6 compatibility, and I really can't understand how to stop this... :(

Comment: huh? jdk 6 doesn't allow multi catch

Comment: supposedly: "...which is valid in Java SE 7 and later..." - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Comment: what does supposedly mean? you said java 7 or later, 6 is before 7.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your last post... I'm not able to remove the JDK6 compatibility from the compiler. Then I'm not able to use multi-catch

Comment: why do you need the compatibility?

Comment: I don't  need it, but Play! (framework) force it. I'm trying solution. When I will find it I will post it here...

Comment: but play says you need 6 or later thus 7 will work

Answer (score 0):

Add the below plugin in maven to compile it using Java version 1.7

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```